# Is it "tiny amount" or "tiny amounts"?

Tags: adjectives, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Can we use *tiny amounts* of something? Or are we have to use only in singular form, such as "*tiny amount* of any liquid"?

I've seen people use *small amounts* and/or *a small amount* of something, but I can't find any example about the *tiny amounts* of something! What are the differences, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite possible to have "tiny amounts"
Examples can be found with a web search.

If there are several "amounts", then the plural is mandatory

> Even though trace gases occur in tiny amounts, they still make a big difference.

(many gases, many tiny amounts of trace gases)

> mix tiny amounts of cadmium red pale with alizarin crimson; add size and paint the red details on the three flowers

(two pigments, a tiny amount of cadmium red pale and a tiny amount of alizarin crimson)

It is also possible in some contexts in which the singular could be used with little difference in meaning:

> The presence of even tiny amounts of fat in an adrenal mass should alert the radiologist to the probable diagnosis of myelolipoma.